# Serial Port Communication With Mobile Phones

Tags: c#, mobile, serial-port

I want to connect my mobile phone to PC Using Serial Port. and communicate and send sms to contacts stored in phone memory.How to achieve this in C#.

Comment: That's a *really* big question! You should break it into smaller steps to get someone willing to help you.

Comment: which phone do you have with a serial port in it? if you tell us the brand model please :) Once you got one, use normal approach for serial port communication as in many examples also here on SO.

Comment: @DavidePiras : We can get Mobile Data Cable to Serial Port Cable n connect to Phone.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are not providing sufficient data to answer this question. Anyway i am writing what i know about this.

I have used two type phones to send sms from the PC and from my micro-controller board, both are with USB connectivity.

In the first case, there is a USB to serial converter inside the data cable, and the USB side is connected to the PC. if you want connect this type phone to PC's serial port, you have to hake the data cable, find out the RX and TX lines which is connected to the phone. Now you can connect the RX,TX and Ground to the serial port, but some times you need a level converter.

In the second case(Currently available phones), the phone itself is a USB device and you can't connect to a serial port. But here the advantage is that, when you install the driver of the phone, you will get one or more **Virtual serial port**, and from the point of a programmer it is a real serial port. You can send AT commands through this port and get the response.